# -T option result in ping command

Tags: linux, ping

I was learning about the `ping` command.

I am not able to understand the output of `ping` command with `-T tsonly` and `-T tsandaddr`.

The output is:

```
$ ping -T tsonly 192.168.1.52
PING 192.168.1.52 (192.168.1.52) 56(124) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.52: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=0.470 ms

 TS:    43448298 absolute
        1
        31
        0
        -31
        0
$ ping -T tsandaddr 192.168.1.52
PING 192.168.1.52 (192.168.1.52) 56(124) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.52: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=0.434 ms

TS: 192.168.2.64    43461227 absolute
    192.168.2.10    0
    192.168.1.52    32
    192.168.1.52    0
```

I searched with google. But I didn't find the answer. In the man page also I didn't find the answer.

I know the absolute time it prints is milliseconds from ut 24 hours midnight time stamp.
Other than that, the remaining three times are what time? Why is that printed in both two `ping` outputs? What is the use of that?

Comment: See my updated answer. Click the big check mark beside my answer if you feel that I answered your question.

Answer (score 6):

The -T option asks nodes (each hop) to insert a timestamp in the IP packets upon receiving a ping. It works by using the TS option of IP packets, specified by [RFC791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791).

ping -T requires one argument of tsonly, tsandaddr or tsprespec. tsonly returns only the timestamp. tsandaddr returns the timstamp and the address the packet was sent from.

**From the man page:**

```
-T timestamp option
      Set special IP  timestamp  options.   timestamp  option  may  be
      either  tsonly  (only  timestamps),  tsandaddr  (timestamps  and
      addresses) or tsprespec host1 [host2 [host3 [host4]]] (timestamp
      prespecified hops).
```

For example, when I ping 192.168.1.10 on my local network from 192.168.1.191, I receive the following output:

```
ping -T tsandaddr 192.168.1.10
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(124) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.32 ms
TS:     192.168.1.191   31636378 absolute
192.168.1.10    6
192.168.1.10    0
192.168.1.191   -1
```

**Update 01**

---

There are four time values returned when you issue the tsandaddr flag. In the example below, we see 31636378 absolute, 6, 0, and -1.

```
ping -T tsandaddr 192.168.1.10
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(124) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.32 ms
TS:     192.168.1.191   31636378 absolute
192.168.1.10    6
192.168.1.10    0
192.168.1.191   -1
```

The large value (31636378) is the number of miliseconds since midnight at UTC, which is why the first number continues to count upward when the -T flag is used. This large number is a reference time.

The first value (6) is the amount of time it took to transmit the ping in miliseconds. The second value(0) is the time in miliseconds it took for the target to receive the ping. The third value (-1) is the amount of time it took to transmit a reply to the sender.

I'm believe the 0 and -1 millisecond values are an indication that the target I pinged did not respond and therefore I am getting useless values.

Feel free to test this command on some websites, some reply with legitimate values.

> --timestamp Send ICMP_TIMESTAMP packets, thereby requesting a timed response from the targetted host.
>
> In successful cases three time values are returned. All are expected
> to state the number of milliseconds since midnight UTC. The first of
> these, ‘icmp_otime’, contains the original time of sending the
> request. Then comes ‘icmp_rtime’, the time of reception by the target,
> and finally, ‘icmp_ttime’, the time of transmitting an answer back to
> the originator.

see --timestamp here: https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/Ping-options.html

Comment: What is that value 6 and 0 and -1 ? Is it a milliseconds ?

Comment: @suresh see my updated answer. Click the big check mark beside my answer if you feel that I answered your question.

Comment: once your ping is successful then only you get the packet received message (64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.32 ms). If the target is not respond then the value is packet received message and time stamp is not printed. So, the ping is succeed. If it is succeed, how you are saying the 0 and -1 are useless values.